# Insert a Picture as the Background of a Figure?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I wish to draw some pedestrian trajectories given the coordinates of every point on the trajectories. This can be easily done using `matplotlib`.

But in my case, the trajectories mean nothing if they are simply drawn over a blank background. *They will only make sense when I overlay them on the real floor map such as the one below.*

[image]

So I am wondering whether it is possible to **make my floor map as the background of the figure**, and then draw the points and trajectories over it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, just plot the map with `imshow` and then plot your lines on top of it.

For example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(500) + 100
y = 50 * np.cos(x / 10.0) + 100

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.imshow(plt.imread('floor_plan.gif'), origin='lower')
ax.autoscale(False)
ax.plot(x, y)

plt.show()
```

[image]